# Now output when debugging hello world in a C script with gdb on Macos (only working when both script.o and a.out present)

Tags: c, macos, gdb

I installed `gdb` on `Macos 11.2.3`. I set it up following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/jasonelwood/setup-gdb-on-macos-in-2020-489k) and have currently a file `.gdbinit` containing `set startup-with-shell off`. I use the following script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
  printf("hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

Then I ran the command:

```
$ gcc -Wall hello_world.c -o hello_world.o
$ gdb hello_world.o
(gdb) run
...
Starting program: /path/to/hello_world.o
[New Thread 0x2403 of process 10983]
```

But don't get the printed `hello world`

Now if generate `a.out` with `gcc hello_world.c` and then run `gdb hello_world.o` (creating both `hello_world.o` and `a.out`) and `(gdb) run` now I get

```
$ gcc -Wall hello_world.c -o hello_world.o
$ gcc hello_world.c
$ gdb hello_world.o
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path/to/hello_world.o
[New Thread 0x2803 of process 15213]
[New Thread 0x1c03 of process 15213]
warning: unhandled dyld version (17)
hello world[Inferior 1 (process 15213) exited normally]
```

It seems that `gdb` works when there are both `hello_world.o` and `a.out` but not `hello_world.o` alone. Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I run `gdb` and getting the `hello world` output without having to compile the script with both `$gcc -Wall hello_world.c -o hello_world.o` and `$ gcc hello_world.c`

**EDIT**
There seems to be a problem with Macos according to [this github link](https://gist.github.com/mike-myers-tob/9a6013124bad7ff074d3297db2c98247) where the following is being said:

```
If after hitting run in `gdb`, you get "Starting program: /path/to/your/executable [args] [New Thread 0x2303 of process 795]" followed by a blank line which does not respond to anything, then you have hit GDB bug 24069. Check that you built the patched version from source.
```

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue for gdb, but do be aware that `.o` is the conventional extension for an *object file*, not a linked executable.

Comment: It seems like MacOS has some restrictions that you'll need to overcome by configuring your GDB. I found [this link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin) and [this link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/20047). They may be of help to you.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @JohnBollinger. But how can I then run `gdb` and getting the `hello world` output without having to compile the script with both `$gcc -Wall hello_01.c -o hello_01.o` and `$ gcc hello_01.c`?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @stanle. Before asking the question, I already followed the step of a similar tutorial (link in the edited question) and already had a `.gdbinit` file with `set startup-with-shell off` on it

Comment: Did you try with a \n at the end of string ?

Comment: thank you for your comment @PtitXav. I added a `\n` but the problem remains

Comment: There seems to have been regular problem in MacOS High Sierra and Catalina about this issue with gab : you may find [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/20047#issuecomment-356513793) useful.

Comment: thanks for your comment @PtitXav. Indeed. I also saw another issue. I am currently try to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to run `hello.o`, which is *not* an executable program, and can not run.

The tutorial you are following creates an *executable* with `gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world -ggdb` (note lack of the `-c` argument).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @EmployedRussian. I tried your command and then ran `$ gdb hello_world` but still get the same problem (plus the command `gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world -ggdb` creates a convoluted hello_world.dSYM directory with many subdirectories). What am I missing? And sorry, but what do you mean by `-c` argument? In which command is it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I could solve the problem following the instruction on [GDB Wiki BuildingOnDarwin](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin)